# How to loop through conversion specifiers in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

How to loop through conversion specifiers in a string in Python 3.11.2? Say I have this code:

```
template = "%(name)s %(age)s"

values = {
    "name": "Jack",
    "age": "50",
    "gender": "male",
}
```

And then I would like to loop through only the conversion specifiers that are inside the string `template`: `name` and `age`. How can I do it?

The reason I want to do this is that both variables `template` and `values` come from a different place. I need to create validation for the template string. Say if the looping could be done like this, I would create validation like this:

```
for specifier in template:
    if not values.get(specifier, None):
        raise Exception(f"Template specifier '{specifier}' does not exist in values!")

template = template % values
```

I might not necessarily need to do this with this old string formatting, if you know how to do a similar thing with new string formatting methods, please do tell. Thank you!

Comment: `template % values` should just work naturally even if there's extra key-values in `values`, so is your question going to be how to raise exception when `values` contains keys that are not in your template?

Comment: @TYZ I know it does work, and no that is not my question. In my use case I want to raise a specific exception in case the template string contains specifiers that do not exist in the `values` dict.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `format` method, only keyword arguments that are needed will be used.

```
>>> template = '{name} {age}'
>>> values = {"name": "Jack", "age": "50", "gender": "male"}
>>> template.format(**values)
'Jack 50'
```

You can also use the [`Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) class (which I find interesting but have rarely, if ever, seen used in the wild).

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> template = Template("$name $age")
>>> template.substitute(values)
'Jack 50'
```

This has the benefit(?) of not having to unpack `values` into multiple keyword arguments first; `substitute` just takes the single mapping as an argument. As of Python 3.11, you can use it to find the identifiers you *do* need

```
>>> template.get_identifiers()
['name', 'age']
```

though as we see above you don't need to use this to produce a stripped-down version of your `values` dictionary.

Comment: Great, the Template class looks exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you :)